# How use sessionStorage with JS and Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, session-storage

I am trying to avoid calling the server-side function `getSuppliersForPoFromSS(orderPo, origin)`, if there isn't data available in the `sessionStorage`, but I am not sure I get the right structure:

```
**/
 * Gets determined supplier from Spreadsheet and builds a select input with options.
 * @param {Object} selecObject
 * @param {String} origin specifying where this is going to be obtained from
 */
function loadSuppliersForPoFromSS(selectObject, origin) {
  orderPo = selectObject.value;
  document.getElementById('selectSupplier').innerHTML = '';
   
  //My shot at it, trying to a 2D array. e.g.: [["Item1", "Item2"]]
  let ar = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(orderPo));
 
   
  if(!ar){   
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
    let select = document.getElementById('selectSupplier');
    let options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (let i = options.length; i--;) {
      select.removeChild(options[i]);
    }
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    select.appendChild(option);
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item.toLowerCase();
      option.text = item;
      select.appendChild(option)
    });
  }).getSuppliersForPoFromSS(orderPo, origin);
 } else {
  //Do I rewrit the part that builds the options with data from sessionStorage?
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but I am not sure I get the right structure:` and `//My shot at it, trying to a 2D array. e.g.: [["Item1", "Item2"]]`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? And, what is `selecObject`?

Comment: Are you looking for i) no data: `!sessionStorage.length`, ii) key `orderPo` not exist: `!(orderPo in sessionStorage)`, iii) 'no value': `!sessionStorage.getItem(orderPo)`, or iv) empty array: `!ar.length`?

Comment: Hi @idfurw! My question is: If there is no data with that ```orderPo``` as the key, then call the server-side and feed the ```select```, but what if there is, within ```else{}```. Do I rewrite the part that builds the ```select``` with existing data repeating the chunk above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since google.script.run is asynchronous, which means the commands following it will not wait for google.script.run to complete and return you can create an internal function `getAr()` which will be called either as part of the success handler of google.script.run or by itself if sessionStorage returns a value.

```
function loadSuppliersForPoFromSS(selectObject, origin) {
  orderPo = selectObject.value;
  document.getElementById('selectSupplier').innerHTML = '';
  
  function getAr(ar) {
    let select = document.getElementById('selectSupplier');
    let options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (let i = options.length; i--;) {
      select.removeChild(options[i]);
    }
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    select.appendChild(option);
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item.toLowerCase();
      option.text = item;
      select.appendChild(option)
    });
  }

  //My shot at it, trying to a 2D array. e.g.: [["Item1", "Item2"]]
  let ar = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(orderPo));
   
  if(!ar){   
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
      getAr(ar);
    }).getSuppliersForPoFromSS(orderPo, origin);
  } 
  else {
    getAr(ar);
  }
}
```

Comment: The function getAr() doesn’t  need to internal. But what I like to do is if it’s not used anywhere else it’s contained in the scope of loadSuppliersForPoFromSS()

Comment: I guess I should set it when I get it from the server-side...? Thank you!